# Why first two images load incorrectly in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, image

I know that the question I have is quite complex, and I really hope someone can help me. I have created an image gallery qih jquery and php. Firstly I am grabbing all the image names from a MySql database, then taking them from the server folder and resizing them with php. It creates the thumbnails, then I created a pop up window with jquery which shows the image in large. After that I place a previous and next button and told jquery to grab the array of image results from php and echo them into the jquery using json. Then it goes through the array to create the next and previous effect. I then centered each individual image when the next and previous button were clicked. When you load the first and second picture it is not centered and it goes to the right. I CAN NOT figure out why this is happening. I really need some help here. There is too much code to post here so I am giving you the website and you can see pretty much everything in the source code. Remember that I am using php so if you are wondering how it is iterating through the pictures that why. Thanks if anyone can help me at all.

http://www.oceanphotostudio.com/test/collection/before-and-after.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's getting offset is that the margins that center the popup div are being calculated before the image is loaded. Notice that on the first click, it will have margins of -37px and -30px. After one image is loaded, calling another one will use the width and height of the last image that was loaded in, which is why you can get unpredictable results.

Take a look at [JQuery's load event handler](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) for information on how to create a callback to resize after the image has been set to load, rather than before.

Answer (score 0):

Your description totally overcomplicates the issue. Browser could care less how you generate the array or html on server, or what language it is

Your position problem is a simple css issue. You've set the `top` and `left` of your popup to 50%. This means top left corner of popup will start at dead center of page, and go right and down from there.

Use a browser console to inspect the html elements and the css rules that apply to them and adjust accordingly. WIthin the console you can make live edits to see impact of the adjustments in real time